# Convert ResultPropertyValueCollection to PsCustomObject

Tags: powershell

Is there a more reliable way to convert a `ResultPropertyValueCollection` created by a `ADSISearcher` query, to a `PsCustomObject`?

Current approach:

```
$properties=@{}

$filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=$Account))"
([ADSISearcher]$filter).FindAll().Properties.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    $properties[$_.Name] = if ($_.Value.Count -gt 1) { $_.Value.ForEach({$_}) -Join ","} else { $_.Value.Item(0) }
}

[PsCustomObject]$properties
```

Comment: What's unreliable about that?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, I don't have a lot of experience w/ the `ADSISearcher` class.  If it creates a more-complex object graph, then my approach probably will miss the grandchildren.  Moreover, I thought there might be a `cast` that might do the work for me, like `[PsCustomObject]@{}`.